# eclipse git lost fetch and commit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-rcp, egit

after doing some changes on my workspace i did a commit an then a fetch from my remote. but i realize there would be a conflict if i do the merge, so i tried to "undo it" the fetch with the option  "Delete Fetch" in Remotes->MyRemote->Fetch , this in Git Repositories tab, i guesed that this would be like a "Ctrl+z", (im new on git) but no, that just erase my configuration to the remote. so my workspace is on this state after that and i dont know how to merge after all,  and be again in the rigth way.

thanks in advance!

[image: current state]

[image: tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the git repo in the Git perspective and choose *Pull*.

Your commit (c601ae3) is still the tip of the local branch *master* and you have fetched all the changes from the origin (who's tip is 191a39a). So if you redo the Pull that should start the merge again.

Alternatively you can do a Merge and then choose *XEON/master* to merge with.